# Which delegate method receive firebase push notification payload in background or terminated state?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In willPresent Notification methods we receive payload when app in foreground state.
Actually I want to generate local notification from firebase push notification response and I couldn't understand which delegate methods is called when application in background and terminated state.

Answer (score 0):

You should always invoke the willPresent method's completionHandler method as it is mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter):

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.banner, .sound])
}
```

With this, you will be able to handle the notification even in backgrounded or terminated state.

Comment: Apple documentation says "Asks the **willPresent**  delegate how to handle a notification that arrived while the app was running in the foreground."